# SQS to Lambda + SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm new with `Lambda` & `SQS` and I'm trying to create a function to send emails, queued in an `SQS` service, but I don't understand how to call the process function that contains the `send` + `delete queue` methods.

Here bellow I paste my code:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const SQS = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
const Lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ apiVersion: '2015-03-31' });
const ses = new AWS.SES({ accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxx", secretAccesskey: "xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx" });
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01", region: "us-west-2" });


const QUEUE_URL = 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/queue';
const PROCESS_MESSAGE = 'process-message';

function getPieceOfMail (path, mapObj, replace) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    s3.getObject({
      Bucket: "myBucket",
      Key: "myKey/" + path
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        if (replace === true) {
            var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"), "gi");
            data = data.Body.toString().replace(re, function (matched) {
              return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
            });
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            resolve(data.Body.toString());
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function getRegisterSource (nickname, activate_link) {
  var activate_link, pieces;

  pieces = [
    getPieceOfMail("starts/start.html", {}, false),
    getPieceOfMail("headers/a.html", {}, false),
    getPieceOfMail("footers/a.html", {}, false),
  ];

  return Promise.all(pieces)
    .then(function (data) {
      return (data[0] + data[1] + data[2]);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return err;
    });
}

function sendEmail (email, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var params = {
            Destination: { ToAddresses: [email] },
            Message: {
              Body: {
                Html: {
                  Data: data
                },
                Text: {
                  Data: data
                }
              },
              Subject: {
                Data: "myData"
              }
            },
            Source: "someone <noreply@mydomain.co>",
        };

        ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function process(message, callback) {
    console.log(message);

    // process message
    getRegisterSource(event['nickname'], event['user_id'])
      .then(function (data) {
        return sendEmail(event["email"], data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("==ERROR==");
        callback(err, err);
      })
      .finally(function () {});

    // delete message
    const params = {
        QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
        ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle,
    };
    SQS.deleteMessage(params, (err) => callback(err, message));
}

function invokePoller(functionName, message) {
    const payload = {
        operation: PROCESS_MESSAGE,
        message,
    };
    const params = {
        FunctionName: functionName,
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        Payload: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(payload)),
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Lambda.invoke(params, (err) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve()));
    });
}

function poll(functionName, callback) {
    const params = {
        QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
        VisibilityTimeout: 10,
    };
    // batch request messages
    SQS.receiveMessage(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        // for each message, reinvoke the function
        const promises = data.Messages.map((message) => invokePoller(functionName, message));
        // complete when all invocations have been made
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            const result = `Messages received: ${data.Messages.length}`;
            callback(null, result);
        });
    });
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        if (event.operation === PROCESS_MESSAGE) {
            console.log("Invoked by poller");
            process(event.message, callback);
        } else {
            console.log("invoked by schedule");
            poll(context.functionName, callback);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

can somebody throw me some light to this?

Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**

After so much misconception, I've decided to start looking on how the [example](http://pastebin.com/pafbuT1d) of polling-SQS works provided by `AWS`.

There I've found that I lacked some basic SQS permissions, but solved now by adding the right policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": ["*"]
    }]
}
```

This allows `Lambda.invoke()` to call `process()`.

When the `process(message, callback)` is called, if I `console.log(message);`, it seems that there's no message, although the queue is being cleared by the line `SQS.deleteMessage(params, (err) => callback(err, message));`

What I was trying was to combine my [sendMail](http://pastebin.com/knD1F5Hw) function that is currently working with a `SQS` service so I only have to `push` each message to the `queue`.

Comment: your code is very long and super spaghetti, 1) consider bundling your email templates/assets with your code, 2) Wrapping `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` in each function is a bad practice, I'd recommend using `function(..., resolve, reject)` pattern, if you clean your code up some more, it'd be easier to focus on the actual problem you're having

Comment: I think I found the problem by giving permissions and separating things: The queue now remove items, but I don't know how can I include my `sendMail` function in the `process` function.

Comment: consider this: `.then(function (data) {
        return sendEmail(event["email"], data);
      })` you need to pass the promise from `sendEmail` directly to `.then` ... try this instead: `.then(sendEmail(event["email"], data))`

Comment: gotta test this! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a common requirement where AWS SES has its own limitations in sending emails at once. If these limitations are violated, the SES account will sandbox itself. It seems like you have solved the problem using proper access credentials.

This code contains a Python3 Lambda code that can be used to handle a situation like this, where a Lambda polls from SQS using threading, and sends emails using SES, without exceeding the given limitations.

Link to [Github Project](https://github.com/Keetmalin/AWS-SQS-SES-Lambda-Thread-Polling).

You can also consider using the new feature in SQS, which is capable of invoking lambdas, when a new message is placed within SQS. But, be careful not to exceed the maximum number of lambda functions within the AWS Account region. (See [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html))